# How can I fix a window with cracked glass?

Tags: windows

I have a bedroom window with cracked glass, and I'm trying to figure out the manufacturer so I can get it fixed.  The windows are double hung, and three pictures are attached.  I looked all over the window, and I could not find any stickers or identifying information.

I'm near Boston, MA and the windows were installed in about 2007.  I know they are not BF Rich, and I talked to someone at Home Depot and he didn't know.

As an alternative, should I contact someone other than the manufacturer to get it fixed?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

It was easy enough to remove the window, and take it to my local glass shop.  They had a new pane put in by the next day.

If it's a screened window, you can do this when the weather is nice.  Otherwise, you'll need to cut a piece of plywood to block the hole while it's being repaired.

Taking it into the shop allows for considerable savings over having the truck come to you.

Call ahead and book a time.  You might have it done in a couple of hours.

Comment: Good suggestion on taking it into the shop.

Comment: Of course, it depends on your ability to secure the area.

Comment: Local shop had to order the glass so I brought the window in to be measured and then put it back.  Glass will arrive in a week and cost me $80.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the manufacturer.  Glass repair is common enough - there should be at least one window/glass repair shops around.

The repair process generally consists of the repair guy measuring the glass, preparing a replacement pane in a shop, then bringing it back to the house and replacing the glass while the window is in the wall.

The downside is it's often as expensive, or nearly as expensive, as simply putting in a new window.