# Fix single hung window glass that is cracked

Tags: repair, windows

My question is somewhat similar to this question - [How can I fix a window with cracked glass?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33230/how-can-i-fix-a-window-with-cracked-glass). The difference is that my window is single hung. The windows are double pane and the inside pane has a big crack. I've attached two pictures. One shows part of the crack. The other shows what the space between the two panes looks like, it's pretty rough. Is there a way for me to fix the window? Or is it at the point where I'd be better off just replacing the whole thing? Given what I have read elsewhere I'm not sure it's possible to remove the top sash, which means I might have to replace the entire window?

Thanks for any info, I really appreciate it.

[image: Crack]

[image: Space between panes]

Comment: Are these all vinyl windows?

Comment: Jack - yes, they are all vinyl. They are only about 6 years old. What happened was that we moved in 3 years ago and I didn't spot the crack. The inspector missed it and I've been dragging my feet on getting it fixed until now.

Comment: that looks like a cosmetic problem. it doesnt look like it was filled with xeon or some kind of insulation medium. check out ebay if you are strapped for cash, alot of eclectic builders merchants on it. i got large 1x1mtr velux windows there for 200 a piece.

Answer (score 2):

I see in the bottom picture, the bottom is a tilt in sash, easy to remove. The top sash CAN be made a tilt in, it is missing the ballasts that keep it from dropping. It is now held in place by a metal or plastic clip that holds it in place. Find these, remove them and the sash will drop, and therefore, able to be removed. I see a screw visible near the tilt latch that may be one of the few to remove in order to drop the upper sash. Then again, that one may do nothing, I would expect to find the screws to lower the sash, under the upper sash, hidden by the lower sash. Remove the lower sash first the rest should go from there.

Most tilt in windows work the same, raise it a little, pull the clips in toward the center, lower the top so the plane of the window is perpendicular to it normal position, and lift one edge up, either the left or right, does not matter.

The rest is the same as the other answer, it will cost a little more maybe since you have the bars between the glass, then again....

Comment: I took out the bottom sash and then removed the 4 screws holding the bar across the bottom part of the top sash. I yanked on it pretty good, but it didn't want to move. How hard can I yank on that? I might try again on a day when it's a little cooler. I mostly wanted to see if it would come loose.

Comment: If you could add a picture of the bottom, the part you removed, just held in place to show how it was, no need to add screws, there is a chance there are screws around the perimeter that were added when the window was built, but need to make sure there is nothing else holding it.

Comment: Jack - Sorry for never getting back to you. I ended up having a glass company do it. I ran out of time and they weren't too expensive. I really appreciate your help.